# How to fix searchBar, not sensitive to uppercase or lowercase?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uppercase, lowercase

When I search in my searchBar using mix of uppercase and lowercase, it doesnt work.

this is my code to filter the search bar

```
filterednames = nameList.filter{(($0.value as! [String:Any])["name"] as! String).contains(searchText)}
```

I want to be able to search for the names even if its a mix of uppercase and lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filterednames = nameList.filter{(($0.value as! [String:Any])["name"] as! String).range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil}
```

adding .range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil will make it case insensitive

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23988893)

Comment: Hi @Nick just want to know if my database structure is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57935114/placing-map-annotation-of-specific-database-value

Comment: If you're storing the car colours in the same table as the user information then you're not properly normalised. It would be better to have them in a separate table (e.g. id, userid, colour, lat, long) with userid a foreign key to the users table.

Comment: im not storing them together. the tableview will contain another list. I just want the map to show red colored cars then later I'll add a function when the annotation is pressed, it will go to another page.

Comment: Should be fine then. Unfortunately I don't know enough about mapkit/freibase to be able to comment on your actual code.

Comment: I would suggest though that you take out one of the database tags and tag it with the actual programming language (swift?) so more people see the question. Otherwise you will waste your bounty.